# Selecting the minimum of two distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm working on a sql selection where I need to get all the smallest records for an ID. My problem is that, while I thought my code was working, it would often return incorrect values for other columns, evidently because of my failure to use having to support my aggregate min function. Here is my code.

```
SELECT *
FROM example_students
INNER JOIN
(SELECT  id, student, test, subject, MIN(score), semester
FROM example_student_scores
WHERE studentid=94
GROUP BY studentid, test, subject) as scores
ON example_students.id=scores.studentid
```

This is what I want my code to do.

> select from exampletable the minimum score for each distinct test and subject combination where the student has id#94

Here are two (heavily modified) tables for the example (I changed all the column names here and in my code too.

```
example_students
id    name
----+-----------+
94    Bob
1023  Thomas
```

.

```
example_students_scores
id    studentId     test       subject     score       semester
----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------

0    94          quiz        math        46          fall
1    94          quiz        math        71          fall
2    94          quiz        math        63          winter
3    94          midterm     math        94          winter
4    94          midterm     science     72          fall
5    94          quiz        math        50          spring
6    94          final       math        76          spring
7    1023        quiz        math        6           spring
8    1023        quiz        math        52          winter
9    1023        quiz        science     68          fall
..*
```

and the results should be

```
results
id    studentId     test       subject     score       semester
----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------
0    94          quiz        math        46          fall
3    94          midterm     math        94          winter
4    94          midterm     science     72          fall
6    94          final       math        76          spring
```

The problem is, I'll get the wrong values for the semester column (and all the other columns I have in my live work).

Given that this has taken me a long time to get no-where with, here is sql to create the two example databases:

```
drop table if exists example_students;
drop table if exists example_students_scores;
create table example_students(
    id int(10) primary key,
    name char(25)
);
create table example_students_scores(
    id int(10) not null,
    studentId int(10) not null,
    test char(20),
    subject char(20),
    score int(10) not null default '0',
    semester char(20),
    primary key (id),
    index studentid (studentid)
);
insert into example_students values ('94','Bob');
insert into example_students values ('1023','Thomas');
insert into example_students_scores values ('0'    ,'94'          ,'quiz'        ,'math'        ,'46'          ,'fall');
insert into example_students_scores values ('1'    ,'94'          ,'quiz'        ,'math'        ,'71'          ,'fall');
insert into example_students_scores values ('2'    ,'94'          ,'quiz'        ,'math'        ,'63'          ,'winter');
insert into example_students_scores values ('3'    ,'94'          ,'midterm'     ,'math'        ,'94'          ,'winter');
insert into example_students_scores values ('4'    ,'94'          ,'midterm'     ,'science'     ,'72'          ,'fall');
insert into example_students_scores values ('5'    ,'94'          ,'quiz'        ,'math'        ,'50'          ,'spring');
insert into example_students_scores values ('6'    ,'94'          ,'final'       ,'math'        ,'76'          ,'spring');
insert into example_students_scores values ('7'    ,'1023'        ,'quiz'        ,'math'        ,'6'           ,'spring');
```

I'd be grateful for any pointers or tips, it's very embarrassing to only figure out that your work is wrong a week after going live!

Comment: `I need to get all the smallest records for an ID.` Please define *smallest record*

Comment: 6 is smaller than 46, which is smaller than 56. 0 is the smallest.

Comment: 6 is not a record, 46 is not a record, 56 is not a record.  They *could* be fields within a record, but which **fields** do you want to compare?

Comment: Please change the second line of student_results to `1    94          quiz        math        46          fall` to see what I mean with duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
select ss2.id score_id,
  ss2.studentid,
  ss1.test,
  ss2.subject,
  ss1.score,
  ss2.semester
from example_students st
left join
(
  select min(score) score, test, subject, studentid
  from example_students_scores
  group by test, studentid, subject
) ss1
  on st.id = ss1.studentid
left join example_students_scores ss2
  on st.id = ss2.studentid
  and ss1.score = ss2.score
  and ss1.test = ss2.test
where st.id = 94
order by ss2.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/276c6/13)

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL when you include a field in the select and not in the group by you get an arbitrary value. In this case you can't simply include the semester and test ID in the group by  because you won't get the results you want.

In order to accomplish this you must find the min score for each student, test, subject and then join it back on to the orginal table

```
SELECT * 
FROM   example_students_scores ess 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT studentid, 
                          test, 
                          subject, 
                          Min(score) score 
                   FROM   example_students_scores 
                   WHERE  studentid = 94 
                   GROUP  BY studentid, 
                             test, 
                             subject) scores 
               ON ess.studentid = scores.studentid 
                  AND ess.test = scores.test 
                  AND ess.subject = scores.subject 
                  AND ess.score = scores.score
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9b73/14)

Another less conventional method is to self anti join on an inequality.

```
SELECT 
    s.*
FROM
    example_students_scores s
    LEFT JOIN example_students_scores s2
    ON s.studentID = s2.studentID
      AND s.test = s2.test
      AND s.subject = s2.subject
      AND s.score > s2.score
WHERE 
     s.studentid = 94 
     AND 
     s2.score is null
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9b73/29)

If you're interested in creating a tie breaker just add an or condition

```
SELECT 
    s.*
FROM
    example_students_scores s
    LEFT JOIN example_students_scores s2
    ON s.studentID = s2.studentID
      AND s.test = s2.test
      AND s.subject = s2.subject
      AND (s.score > s2.score
           or s.id > s2.id ) -- Added for tie breaker

WHERE 
     s.studentid = 94 
     AND 
     s2.score is null
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dee89/7) Note: I modified the data to include a tie situation

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know you could perform a join on multiple expressions!

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
select es.name, e.studentid, e.test, e.subject, e.score as MinScore, e.semester 
from  example_students_scores e
join (
       select studentid, test, subject, min(score) as score
       from example_students_scores
        group by studentid, test, subject) e2 on  e.studentid=e2.studentid
                                              and e.test=e2.test 
                                              and e.subject=e2.subject
                                              and e.score=e2.score
join example_students es on e.studentid = es.id
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01d36/12/0) Demo

Answer (score 1):

If two example_student_scores happen to have the same score, you'll need to avoid duplicates in the output. Min() would cause duplicates.

An excellent way to perform the task is to use window functions, and row_number().

If window functions are not available, the following way to simulate the "first-of-a-group" functionality could be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM example_students es
JOIN example_student_scores ss ON ss.studentid= es.id
WHERE es.id = 94
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM example_student_scores nx
        WHERE nx.studentid = ss.studentid
        AND nx.test = ss.test
        AND nx.subject = ss.subject
        AND ( nx.score < ss.score
                -- tie breaker
                OR ( nx.score == ss.score AND nx.id < ss.id)
                )
        )
        ;
```

Comment: Very nice. I was trying to figure out a nice way to do a tie breaker without a partitioned row_number or another subquery and your answer inspired my last query. Note that simulating a row number in MySQL is easy but I haven't figured out how to do a partitioned one. As an aside you have a couple of syntax errors. (`==` and the three part names `nx.scores.studentid` and `ss.scores.studentid`)

Comment: Sorry about the 3level names. they were caused by copypasting your fragment and adding correlation names at the last moment.

Answer (score 1):

with correlated subquery

```
select 
   * 
from 
   example_students_scores s1 
where 
   studentId = 94 and 
   score  = (select 
                 min(score)
             from 
                 example_students_scores s2 
             where
                 s2.studentId = s1.studentId and 
                 s2.subject = s1.subject and 
                 s2.test = s1.test 
             group by 
                 studentId, test, subject
            )
```

[Demo with SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ca85/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Does the following query do what you want?

```
  SELECT  test, subject, MIN(score) as minscore
  FROM example_student_scores
  WHERE studentid=94
  GROUP BY test, subject
```

Answer (score 0):

Just SELECT and  GROUP BY the columns you need :

```
SELECT *
FROM example_students
INNER JOIN
(SELECT studentid, test, subject, MIN(score), semester
FROM example_student_scores
GROUP BY studentid, test, subject,semester) scores
ON example_students.id=scores.studentid
WHERE studentid=94
```

When you use an aggregation function on a column, all the other attributes in the SELECT clause must appear in the GROUP BY clause.

The rest of the query sounds good for me.

Comment: The testID is missing from your results. Also it would produce 8 records instead of 4